# Why it works: BigDecimal Sum with Reduce and BigDecimal::add

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I can understand why Total1 is calculated, but as Total2 is calculated I have no idea!
How can a **BigDecimal::add** be used in a **BiFunction**? Signatures are not the same !!!

```
package br.com.jorge.java8.streams.bigdecimal;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BigDecimalSumTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<BigDecimal> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new BigDecimal("1"));
        list.add(new BigDecimal("2"));

        BigDecimal total1 = list.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (t, v) -> t.add(v));

        BigDecimal total2 = list.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);

        System.out.println("Total 1: " + total1);
        System.out.println("Total 2: " + total2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its used as a **[`BinaryOperator<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html)** in your current context.

Its equivalent lambda representation:

```
(bigDecimal, augend) -> bigDecimal.add(augend) // same as in your previous line of code
```

and anonymous class representation:

```
new BinaryOperator<BigDecimal>() {
    @Override
    public BigDecimal apply(BigDecimal bigDecimal, BigDecimal augend) {
        return bigDecimal.add(augend);
    }
}
```

where `BinaryOperator<T> extends BiFunction<T,T,T>`, meaning its *a specialization of `BiFunction` for the case where the operands and the result are all of the same type.*

Added to that, your code is actually using one of the overloaded implementations of `reduce` method i.e. [`Stream.reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

---

> How can a BigDecimal::add be used in a BiFunction

Just a step further and *only for explanation*, there is also an overloaded implementation that uses `combiner` as in [`Stream.reduce​(U identity, BiFunction<U,​? super T,​U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(U,java.util.function.BiFunction,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) which would look like :

```
BigDecimal total = list.stream()
                       .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add, BigDecimal::add);
//                                                   ^^                ^^
//                                              BiFunction here    BinaryOperator here
```

Comment: Really nice and complete answer!

Answer (score 4):

Given `BigDecimal::add` is being used as a `BiFunction<BigDecimal, BigDecimal, BigDecimal>`, the compiler will look for one of two eligible signatures.

The first possible signature, as you have picked up on, would be a two-argument static method. The relevant lambda would be `(a, b) -> BigDecimal.add(a, b)`. Of course, you are correct to recognise that this doesn't exist.

The second possible signature would be a one-argument instance method. The equivalent lambda here would be `(a, b) -> a.add(b)`. As this one exists and the other does not, this is how the compiler would interpret it.